# Minor bug in tab CSS

Tags: bug, design, tabs

When I move mouse to the very top of non selected tab (at the border) , it starts trembling. Such tabs can be found in any [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) or in any user's profile.

[image: SO tab]

It is minor, but it can be very easily solved - is it worth the effort? Tested on Chrome browser.

Comment: Do you think that is a bug? I like that animation.

Comment: looks fine for me o.O

Comment: @hims056 yeah, it's pretty cool. My humble processor agrees: he spends half of his time on the animation.

Comment: This has been brought up various times, but it was never fixed afaik.

Comment: It would be cool if I wasn't epileptic.